# emacs+perl: possible to get vim's syntax coloring style?

Tags: perl, emacs, syntax-highlighting, vi

I really like (and am used to) vim's syntax coloring style for perl programs.

Is there a way to get that style under emacs? I've tried (vanilla) `perl-mode` and `cperl-mode`.

If it makes any difference, I'm using Ubuntu and emacs23-nox in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax colouring is done by some sort of scripting; as vim and emacs use entirely different syntax description and scripting system, it's obviously impossible to get vim syntax colouring under emacs automatically. On the other hand, you could build your own syntax highlighting mode for perl, using the same colors and fonts as vim does; this is probably a big work, but it's doable. See the [emacs documentation on font-lock-mode](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Font-Lock.html).